# how to set autolayout for label and button horizontal?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set autolayout for a `UILabel` titled "Have an account?" and a `UIButton` "sign up" which are placed in a view, not in view controller. The view however is inside the view controller. The spacing between the `UIlabel` and the `UIButton` is zero. Both are placed in middle of the view and at the bottom side like this

```
Have an account ? Sign Up
```

I have tried the following solutions

step - 1

for label: (1) leading (2) bottom (3) height constraints

step - 2

for button: (1) trailing (2) bottom (3) height constraints

step - 3

Press and drag from `UIButton` to `UILabel` and select horizontal spacing.

Here both button and label width are different.

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: Use UIStackView

Comment: Yea StackView is what you want :)

Comment: Sohan, welcome to Stackoverflow. You have to show/mention similar links/tutorials which you've tried and then come and ask. Can you edit your question and include them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution is `UIStackView`.

If you don't want use that then you can do one more thing:

Add a `UIView` having constraint :

1. Bottom
2. Fix width and height
3. horizontally centre align.

place both the label and signup button in it.

Check this image for reference:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find it easier to use a `Horizontal Stack View`, set its `distribution` property to `Fill` and its `alignment` property to `Center`.

Answer (score 0):

UIStackView is a good way to do this, But this way is also not that hard.

1) Label -> Left, Top, Bottom

2) Button -> Right, Top, Bottom

3) Label - Button horizontal gap

4) Set the height of the container view (not the VC view)

5) Set centre and bottom(Y constraint) of container view within the 
viewController main view

containerView contains both Label & button and containerView is on View Controller main view